# Center a background image in mobile safari, landscape *and* portrait (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have a background image that is 1024 x 1024 pixels; the reason for these dimensions is that I want the image cover the screen in both *landscape* and *portrait* modes. The image has a small logo right in the center of it, but otherwise it is a simple gradient. I want the image always centered; in other words, the logo must always in the center of the screen, in *landscape* and *portrait* orientations. I also want the image covering the whole screen, but don't want the background image creating unnecessary scrollbars; so I don't want it to be possible to move the image by dragging it around the screen.

Here is what I have tried (and for the sake of this example I am just using a style tag in the HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
    html,body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
        background-position:center;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hello world.        
</body>
</html>
```

The issue with the code here is that the image is not centered (in *portrait* mode the logo shows to the right of the screen, in *landscape* at the bottom of the screen). It also seems that the background image becomes part of the page content so it causes scrollbars, meaning that the image can be dragged left and right.

I would prefer a solution that is just CSS and html, but will accept one with Javascript if it works. Please don't mention issues pertaining to other browsers here, I am specifically asking about Mobile Safari in this question. I have tried a *LOT* of the suggestions made in various answers and I am yet to find a solution that works correctly in Mobile Safari.

So here are my requirements again in point form:

- background image always covers the whole screen (no white space showing)
- image always centered (so overflow evenly divided between left and right/top and bottom)
- image stays centered when iPad is rotated between landscape and portrait
- background image is fixed (cannot be moved)
- preferably a solution using just HTML and CSS (CSS3 is also fine)

Anwyone know how this can be done?

Update:

This problem might lie between the computer and the chair! ;) I will post an update when I have sorted out an issue in my UIWebview.

Ok. It is confirmed. There is nothing to see here! :) This problem was all of my own doing and the HTML that I provided actually works correctly. This went wrong because the HTML being loaded is an error screen and in trying to "fake" the error situation I caused an actual error where the UIWebview was loaded before it was ready. When I load the HTML at the correct time, then the centering suddenly works and the scrollbars dissappear. Everything 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background images have no height and width, their height and width is dependent on the parent's height and width in which they are applied to. So it is impossible for a background image to create scroll bars.

If you want the background image to resize depending on the screen size, use this:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. Hopefully this works out for you. If not, comment back and I'll keep working at it. Again, I didn't test this, and I rarely used the COVER parameter, but I know it covers the whole page, I'm just not positive how it keeps the proportions of the image.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Hmmm, I thought that background image shouldn't cause scrollbars, and from a test did seems you are right about the scrollbars. My HTML is displaying inside a UIWebView and it seems I have an issue in my UIWebview that is causing the scrollbars and possibly the misaligned centering as well. I will get back to this question after I have sorted out my issue with the web view. Is there an embarrassed smiley that I can used in stackoverflow? haha ;)

Comment: Oh no embarrassment necessary :) I post INCREDIBLY dumb questions on here and get chewed out sometimes haha. This was a valid question.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Mike. I am going to give you the credit and flag your answer correct for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks. :)